# Why does negative z-index works better than positive z-index?

Tags: html, css, canvas

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/sachya/pen/QjjxJw

I tried to put canvas as background and content in front. What gave a strange feeling is that:

First i set canvas to `z-index:22` and content to `z-index:44` and it didn't work. Then i just gave canvas `z-index:-1`, and it worked

Comment: `z-index` only works if `position` is set on each element and those two elements are siblings.

Comment: i had position set over canvas as absolute and display static. How come siblings affect z-index if we are going to use overlapping contents?

Comment: `position: static` is the default positioning which means position is not set. It needs to be `absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`. Start here if you want to learn more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index